# Is this a matrix norm?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

In [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm), the operator norm of a matrix is given by (assume: real, $n$-dimensional)

$$ ||A||= \max \left\{ \frac{|Ax|}{|x|}:x \in \mathbb{R}^n, x\neq 0 \right\}$$

(I'm not sure why it is not a supremum, maybe the set is closed.)

Then is it true that the following is also a norm? $$ ||A||= \inf \left\{ \frac{|Ax|}{|x|}:x \in \mathbb{R}^n, x\neq 0 \right\}$$

(Actually I want to say something like $|Ax|\ge||A||\,|x|$)

Comment: you can define the right hand side of second equation as something but not as a norm. the infimum can be zero without the matrix being $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A norm needs to satisfy $\|A\|=0\iff A=0$.  Therefore every projection onto some proper vector subspace $W$ will have norm $0$ with the choice $x\in W^\perp$.  This is necessarily a problem.

We can see that the triangle inequality has troubles with this norm too.  Letting $p$ be the projection onto $W$ and $p'$ the projection onto $W^\perp$, then
$$
0=\|p\|+\|p'\|\geq\|p+p'\|=\|\text{Id}\|=1
$$
is a contradiction.

Comment: It appears to me that you're *proving* that neither of the $||\,\cdot \,||$ defined in the question are norms. I know that at least the $\max$ one is. I'm not sure what you mean the projection you're mentioning. Is $W$ a set of matrices or a set of vectors?

Comment: The $\max/\sup$ one definitely is. I'm addressing the question 'is it true that the following is also a norm?'  It is not.  I will clarify $W$.